# Add event listener for all images that are not inside an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I select all `<img>` elements that are not inside of an `<a>` anchor without any libraries in vanilla JavaScript (without any libraries)?
What is the most performance-savvy way to do it?

Comment: There's no direct native way, as there's no parent selectors, and `:not()` is not fully implemented. One way is to create an array of all the images, then filter it, like so: `offLinkImgs = imgs.filter(img => !img.closest('a'))`.

Comment: @Teemu I came to think :not is quite broadly supported nowadays. Isn't it the case? It's not parent selector, OP doesn't want to do something on the anchor containing an image, but on images contained in an anchor

Comment: It is supported by majority of popular browsers. But yes, it's not yet fully supported by the less popular browsers. Check it on caniuse.

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes, that's the case. The basic `:not` is probably supported quite widely, but all the properties it can contain are not implemented yet in the browsers. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) says: "_The ability to list more than one selector is experimental and not yet widely supported._" And for this task we'd need multiple selectors for `:not` to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be really simple:

```js
// Use CSS-like selector
const images = document.querySelectorAll(":not(a) > img");

// Foreach it

images.forEach((img) => {
// Use the img variable
}
```